# How can I convert PHP DB data to JSON with different titles for columns

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

How can I convert php data sent from a controller to my view, into JSON objects with new titles defined, and be able to wrap it in a script html tag. I would like the data to have the same titles as they have been set in my view below, although the database titles are different.

controller,

```
$deals = "SELECT deals.id, categories.category_name, deals.title, deals.price, deals.imagepath FROM deals INNER JOIN categories on     deals.category_fk = categories.id INNER JOIN masters on masters.id =     deals.masterid_fk";

$deals = DB::select($deals);

 return view('pages.home',['deals'=> $deals]);
 }
 }
```

on my view i have:

```
@foreach ($deals as $deal)


"id": {{$deal->id}},
"category": {{$deal->category_name}},
"sub_category": {{$deal->master_name}},
"rating": "5",
"title": {{$deal->title}},
"price": {{$deal->price}},
"image": "{{$deal->imagepath}}"


@endforeach
```

I want my end product to look like this 
     
      [

```
    { 
      "id": 225,
      "category": "Home",
      "sub_category": "Dusting",
      "rating": "3",
      "title": "Complete dusting of all furniture",
      "price": "$8,000",
      "image": "/img/apartment-architecture-carpet-584399.jpg"
    }
 ]
 </script>
```

Comment: You should do that in the controller and not in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the data and generate the Array and transform into a JSON:

```
$for_json = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach ($deals as $deal){
   $for_json[$counter]['id']           = $deal->id;
   $for_json[$counter]['category']     = $deal->category_name;
   $for_json[$counter]['sub_category'] = $deal->master_name;
   $for_json[$counter]['rating']       = 5;
   $for_json[$counter]['title']        = $deal->title;
   $for_json[$counter]['price']        = $deal->price;
   $for_json[$counter]['image']        = $deal->imagepath
   $counter++;
}

$deals = json_encode($for_json);
```

This is for your controller.

Comment: When I run this I get only one row from the DB when it should be more. what could be missing?